# Как сделать подобный код на нативном JS?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Всем привет

Есть такой код на jQuery, но я не могу переписать его на нативный JS. Подскажите, как нужно сделать:

```
var aboutUs = $('#about_us').offset().top;
var quality = $('#quality').offset().top;
    if (scrolledFromTop > aboutUs && scrolledFromTop < quality) {
      $('.header__list li a').removeClass('active');
      $('.about-us').addClass('active')
    }
```

Спасибо

Comment: А что не понятно?

Comment: @Doofy не нашел аналог offset().top на нативе

Comment: `element.offsetTop`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Например так:

```
var aboutUs = document.querySelector('#about_us').offsetTop;
var quality = document.querySelector('#quality').offsetTop;
var header = document.querySelectorAll(".header__list li a");
var about = document.querySelectorAll(".about-us");
    if (scrolledFromTop > aboutUs && scrolledFromTop < quality) {
      [].forEach.call(header, element => element.className.replace('active', ''))
      [].forEach.call(about, element => element.className += ' active')
    }
```

Comment: код не аналогичен - код из вопроса может работать если несколько элементов _'.header__list li a'_, а из ответа - нет

Comment: @Grundy, Исправил код

Comment: тут лучше не `for..in` а обычный `for`, или методами из `Array.prototype`, типа `forEach`

Comment: @Grundy, вы правы - сделал.

Comment: единственное дополнение: в текущем виде будет работать **только в Chrome**, потому что _document.querySelectorAll_ - возвращает не массив, и функцию `forEach` для этой коллекции только хром добавляет

Comment: @Grundy, пофиксил

Answer (score 1):

```
aboutUs = document.querySelector('#about_us').offsetTop;
quality = document.querySelector('#quality').offsetTop;

if(scrolledFromTop > aboutUs && scrolledFromTop < quality) {
    headerList = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('.header__list li a'));
    headerList.forEach((e) => e.classList.remove('active'));
    document.querySelector('.about-us').classList.add('active');
}
```